# Is Adobe AIR a good choice for building an app usage-monitoring tool?

Tags: air, adobe

I've been looking for some some answers about Adobe AIR in its current version and I'm wondering if any of you could let me know if I can do all these things with an Adobe AIR app, since I know they have their limitations:

- Sit in the system tray in Windows and as a small icon in the top-most bar in OS X while running in the background? Will this require different programming to support both platforms?
- While being in the background, be notified of which app gets the focus and when? Ideally, I would also get the name of the document, URL of the website (if we're on a browser with tabs) that has the focus, etc. I'm trying to build a tool similar to RescueTime, that tells you how much time you spent on each app or website.
- Have a specific system-wide hotkey (like Alt+Space) that when pressed, the app comes up into focus (from being in the background)?
- Show notifications (Growl-style unintrusive popups) for specific events?
- Being notified when the system gets inactive (screensaver pops up, users "sleeps" computer, etc)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, system tray is supported in unified way
2. No, AIR has no knowledge of other applications.
3. No global hotkey support
4. Yes
5. No

AIR isn't created with system programming in mind, it has web roots. Items 2, 3 and 5 could be done with native helper, but this require system programming for each target platform.

Comment: #2 is possible with Native Process (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) and #5 is possible with NativeApplication Events (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html)

Comment: @TheDarkIn1978 I've been looking at NativeProcess and it seems it's only to keep track of apps you've launched using your AIR app, is that correct? How would I get notified when the active app changes (alt + tab, etc)?

Comment: no.  NativeProcess can be used to read your computers activity, to know which apps are open and closed.  basically it can do anything you can do on the command line.  if there's something it can't do, you can write a small helper application in another language and us it as a proxy, but that should be largely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

yes.  all of that can be accomplished with and AIR application using [NativeApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html) and [NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html).

in order to write once and deploy on Windows and Mac, you will need to determine which OS your application is running either by employing the NativeApplication properties:

- NativeApplication.supportsDockIcon (Mac OS X)
- NativeApplication.supportsSystemTrayIcon (Windows)

or you can determine the OS more precisely like this:

```
//Resoslve Operating System
if  (Capabilities.os.toLowerCase().indexOf("win") > -1)
    {
    //Native Processes for Windows  
    }
    else if (Capabilities.os.toLowerCase().indexOf("mac") > -1)
    {
    //Native Processes for Mac OS X
    }
    else if (Capabilities.os.toLowerCase().indexOf("linux") > -1)
    {
    //Native Process for Linux
    }
    else
    {
    throw new Error("Unresolved Operating System");
    }
```

while this approach will only require you to write the application once, AIR applications that use system specific processes (Native Processes) must be published with native installers for each target OS as those native processes are different for each OS.

some native processes (such as reading data from a serial port or printer driver) may require a small, helper application, perhaps written in C++, to be used as a proxy that is controlled by AIR for communication between AIR and the target process.

further reading:  [Interacting with a native process](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html)